# How to choose what object to lock on in Java?

Tags: java, concurrency

I have read answers to similar questions about the correct ways to use synchronized. However, they dont seem to explain why this issue occurred.
Even though I added synchronized to my getValue and setValue method, i still get outputs like the following.
Why does this happen?

**output:**

> making  set
>
> Doing  get
>
> making  set
>
> Doing  making  set
>
> get
>
> Doing  get
>
> making  set
>
> making  Doing  get
>
> set

**Code:**

```
package src;

public class StackNode {
private Object value;
private StackNode next;

private final Object lock = new Object();

public StackNode() {
    setValue(null);
    setNext(null);
}

public StackNode(Object o) {
    value = 0;
    next = null;
}

public StackNode(StackNode node) {
    value = node.getValue();
    next = node.getNext();
}

public synchronized Object getValue() {
        System.out.print(" Doing ");
        System.out.println(" get ");
        System.out.flush();
        return value;

}

public  synchronized void setValue(Object value) {
        System.out.print(" making ");
        System.out.println(" set ");
        System.out.flush();
        this.value = value;
}

public synchronized StackNode getNext() {
    return next;
}

public synchronized void setNext(StackNode next) {
    this.next = next;
}
}
```

Test:

```
public class TestStackNode {
private final static StackNode node = new StackNode();

    @Test
public void getSetValueTest() throws InterruptedException{
    node.setValue("bad");
    Runnable setValue = new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            node.setNext(new StackNode());
            node.setValue("new");
        }
    };
    
    Runnable getValue = new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Assert.assertEquals("new", node.getValue());
        }
    };
    List<Thread> set = new ArrayList<Thread> ();
    List<Thread> get = new ArrayList<Thread> ();
    for (int i = 0; i < 30000; i++){
        set.add( new Thread(setValue));
        get.add(new Thread(getValue));
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 30000; i++){
        set.get(i).start();
        get.get(i).start();
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 30000; i++){
        set.get(i).join();
        get.get(i).join();
    }
}
```

Comment: The synchronized methods interleave with each other as I get outputs like making doing get [new line] set.

Comment: Are you sure both threads are working with the same object?

Comment: yes. I posted my junit testing code as well. You can take a look at it.

Comment: Please post the entire test case.

Comment: Yep. Entire test has been posted. Check it out

Comment: I tested and output looks fine to me. Can you paste your output

Comment: I had 30000 threads running. the output is very long. But I posted a piece of it.

Answer (score 4):

This should fix the issue.

```
public Object getValue() {
  synchronized(System.out){
    System.out.print(" Doing ");
    System.out.println(" get ");
    System.out.flush();
    return value;
  }

}
```

Comment: Perfect. Resolves the issue. The problem is with printing sequence, threads work fine.

Comment: Taken literally, this is obviously not true -- having one method synchronized on `System.out` and the other on the `StackNode` instance practically *guarantees* interleaving of output -- but perhaps if you add some explanation of what you're going for, this answer can be made useful?

Comment: Oh, i meant locking all the setter and getters by System.out instead of using the synchronized key word.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your no-arg constructor calls `setValue(...)` on the newly-created instance:

```
public StackNode() {
    setValue(null);
    setNext(null);
}
```

and your `Runnable setValue` constructs a new instance of `StackNode`, to pass to `node.setNext(...)`:

```
            node.setNext(new StackNode());
```

(even though your test never actually uses `node.next`, so this is essentially a no-op aside from the output it produces). Since your `synchronized` methods are *instance* methods (not `static` methods), they have separate locks, which means that the call to `setValue(...)` in the new instances' constructors is not synchronized with respect to the calls you make on `node`.

Note that, although your specific problem is rather unusual (you have a getter and setter that are manipulating shared external state, namely `System.out`, but do not have any corresponding shared locks to prevent interference), it is actually *always* a bad idea to call a method from a constructor, unless the method is `private` or `final` or `static` or the class is `final`, because a superclass constructor is called before a subclass instance is fully created, so if the constructor calls a method that's overridden in a subclass, the subclass method will receive an incomplete `this` object and might misbehave terribly. You're better off changing your constructor to this:

```
public StackNode() {
    value = null;
    next = null;
}
```

(or just remove the assignment statements altogether, since fields of reference type are automatically initialized to `null` anyway).

Comment: Great analysis.  The question was "why does this happen", and you have provided a fine answer.